# high virtual memory usage for the application after upgrading from Java 6 to Java 8

Tags: java-8, virtual-memory, java-6

We have a Java application that fetches data from external system and creates a memory map of the data.
Earlier the application was built using Java 6. As part of compliance, we needed to upgrade to Java 8.
We just built the application using Java 8 compiler and started testing it.
We observed that there is increase in consumption of Virtual memory by the application.

With Java 6 it was consuming around **5 GB** whereas with Java 8 it's at **38 GB**.

I am looking for suggestions on how should I approach in finding the problem.
The resident memory of the application is 5 GB as before.

Comment: I think you should rephrase the question to be stackoverflow compliant and first state what you have tried before you ask what might the potential issues be. There is also no mention about much of the programs details as well such as whether the information it is storing has potentially increased etc? These types of question are generally asked as interview type questions.

Comment: You probably want to start with explaining what data structures and algorithms your code is using in order to determine if there was some change in the way java handles that data structure or some bad practice of gc. Once that is done, figure out which variables are fixed and what has changed and then potentially re-ask the question

Comment: this is not interview question. "I am looking for suggestions on how should I approach in finding the problem." This is what I mentioned in the question.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, there is 0 change in the code. All we have done is just compile it against Java 8 and run it. If the data structures / member variables , etc have any impact, why wasn't the case with Java 6 ? I am looking for suggestions on what can I check in these cases.

Comment: That's my point, stackoverflow does not help in finding ***suggestions*** as it is a waste of time without having hard parameters. I did give suggestions on what to start with.

Comment: Not in your code, but how did Java change the architecture of the datastructures. For example, java improved concurrency from 6 to 8. Maybe you are using a library that was good in 6 but not anymore in 8. Maybe they added more features to data structures and they take more memory now if you store them etc.

Comment: Ok . Understood. I will get back. I can paste the code for sure.

Comment: Awesome! But you see now what I mean by interview questions :D Because it's hard to point your finger on any one possible cause. Also, garbage collection could be a cause if concurrency is being used.